# Get all fields from google spreadsheet with api v4

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm setting up a project in NodeJS and for testing I get the information from a `spreadsheet` in JSON format from the following page: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet

To obtain the information of a sheet, in the spreadsheetId field I put the ID of the spreadsheet and in the range field the name of the sheet.

This is the JSON I get:

```
{
  "spreadsheetId": "{spreadsheetId}",
  "valueRanges": [
    {
      "range": "Parameters!A1:Z1000",
      "majorDimension": "ROWS",
      "values": [
        [
          "Country",
          "COLOMBIA"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want is to show all the fields of the sheet to obtain the title and the modification and creation dates. To do this, in the `fields` field, I am putting the `title` string but I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "title",
            "description": "Error expanding 'fields' parameter. Cannot find matching fields for path 'title'."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried putting * but I get the same JSON.

**My problem:** How can I get the date of creation and the date of last modification of the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use this endpoint to get a spreadsheet properties: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get

Comment: Ok, that returns a lot of fields, but what is the field that tells me the creation date and the date of the last modification of the spreadsheet?

Comment: I can't find the date fields from that api. How can I find those fields? Is there another url from which they are displayed?

Comment: you can use Drive API to get file properties, including creation and modification dates

Comment: Ok I got it. I have another question related to google APIs, can you help me please